# Showing episodes as numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

We build a little program with some loops because this is what we are learning right now.
Is there a way to write it so that the program sees the number and than gives them out i.e sees season 2 has 22 episodes and then gives out 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

We now should give out the amount of episodes as the numbers i.e for season 2 it would be every number from 1 to 22.

I know I can look at how much episodes there are in a season and write

`for(i=1; i<=22; i++){ console.log(i); }`

I tried to look a solution on how to do this but I couldn't find one.

```js
const myFavSeries = {
  title: `Scrubs`,
  director: `Bill Lawrence`,
  year: `2001 - 2010`,
  description: `In this series we follow JD as he starts his journey from a fresh medicine college alumni in to becoming a doctor. During this adventure he encounters a lot of ups and downs.`,
  seasons: [{
      episodes: 24,
      startYear: `02.10.2001`,
      endYear: `21.05.2002`
    },
    {
      episodes: 22,
      startYear: `26.09.2002`,
      endYear: `17.04.2003`
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite your question so it was readable and understandable. I also made you a snippet. Please add your attempt in a [mcve]

Comment: Also JS arrays start at 0

Comment: @mplungjan please don't convert code that doesn't need to run to a snippet. A code block is fine.

Comment: You were quite close, Note the (i+1) to show the 0-based counter of seasons:  `for (let i = 0, seasons = myFavSeries.seasons.length; i < seasons; i++) { const season = myFavSeries.seasons[i]; for (let j = 1, episodes = season.episodes; j <= episodes; j++) { console.log("season", (i + 1), "episode", j) }` 
}

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but essentially they all involve a loop as you'll need to get every integer between 0 and the number of episodes. One other way to do it would be to use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). I wrote an example of that here: https://jsfiddle.net/ya7ubcvt/

Comment: @mplungjan I've [asked for opinions on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420279/should-we-help-noobs-write-snippets-if-the-code-doesnt-require-snippet-funct) on whether or not we should have snippets for cases like this.

Comment: @Cerbrus they misunderstood your question so yeah - I still think newcomers should be taught to use snippets and then he could have added the attempt on the object instead of `for(i=1; i<=22; i++){ console.log(i); }`

Comment: Then please explain to them how they misunderstood it, @mplungjan

Comment: @Cerbrus I did..

Answer (score 0):

1. Access the list of episodes: `myFavSeries.seasons`
2. Get the second season: `myFavSeries.seasons[1]`
3. Get the number of episodes: `myFavSeries.seasons[1].episodes`

Then use your `for` loop, replacing 22 by the value found in step 3.

Note: If you need to do that for all seasons, you can change step 2 by a `for` loop from `0` to `myFavSeries.seasons.length`

Comment: Thanks everyone my code is no working.
I already postet a second question probably pretty easy to answer but I just can´t find a solution.